# Linux gcc compile problems

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am new to Linux and I tried to compile a library. CMAKE works great to configure but when compile with make I get errors like this:

error: ‘____stat64’ was not declared in this scope
____stat64 statbuf;
error: ‘____stat64’ was not declared in this scope
____stat64 statbuf;
error: ‘getcwd’ was not declared in this scope
if (NULL != getcwd(chFile, _MAX_PATH))

Maybe I have a problem with missing header files? My gcc version is 
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)

Thanks,
Ingo

Comment: Have you installed the linux headers? https://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that you have the linux headers installed on your machine. To make sure they are installed, on Debian based distros, run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Also verify that you are including `unistd` header as Michael Surette already showed. For clarity you would include the header mentioned as the code below:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I try to add headers the system told me that they are already installed. So I think this is not the issue.

Comment: Then you should include the header on your compile unit.

Comment: How to do this (Newbie)?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear to you what I meant @Ingo.

Answer (score 1):

If you type `man 3p getcwd` in a terminal, you will find that you need

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

to call getcwd.

The modern C++ cross-platform way to do this is to use the `filesystem` header and the `current_path()` function.

Comment: If I type man 3p getcwd I get: No manual entry for getcwd in section 3p

Comment: Some distros don't install man pages by default. My OpenSUSE does. If yours doesn't, Google it and you will get the man page.

Comment: You should get a result typing in man getcwd and that will point you the location of this function on the correct header, which is `unistd`.